# Where is the Redguard woman?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was approached by a few underhanded Redguard men calling themselves the Alik'r in Whiterun, who wanted a Redguard woman. The only Redguard woman I found in Whiterun won't shut up about marriage and has no meaningful dialog options. Where can I find her?

[image]

Comment: I assume the women who aked about the marriage you thought the Redguard woman was is Ahlam, who sits at the Gildergreen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look for a woman named **Saadia** in the **Bannered Mare** tavern in Whiterun, usually in a side room. She was cooking in the kitchen when I found her.

If she isn't there, make sure to wait some time. She is known to be outside and then come to the inn (depending on hour).

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble making the marker come up on your map, make sure you de-select all other quests in your journal. Then select the individual quest ONLY (especially in the "miscellaneous" sub-menu.)